# How do I add and remove class while scrolling past an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need the `.fixie` class to be added to a div once it scrolls past the start of another div, and removed again once it scrolls past the end of it. I've got the first part working, `.fixie` is added correctly, but how do I remove the class again once I've scrolled past the element?

```js
function sticky_relocate_2() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('.r_box').offset().top - 100;
    
    console.log(window_top,div_top);

    if (window_top > div_top) {
            $('.fixie').addClass('sticky')


    } else 
            $('.fixie').removeClass('sticky')

}

$(window).scroll(sticky_relocate_2);
```

```css
.wrap{ 
    height:2000px; 
    width:100%;
}
.fixed_line{ 
    border-bottom:1px solid #000; 
    height:100px; width:100%; 
    margin-bottom:100px; 
    background-color:#72cbeb; 
    position:fixed;
}
.container{ 
    padding-top:200px;
}
.left{ 
    float:left; 
}
.l_box{ 
    width:200px; 
    background-color:#CCC; 
}
.r_box, .fixie{ 
    width:100px; 
    background-color:#999; 
}

.sticky{
  position:fixed;
  top:100px;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='fixed_line'></div>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='left l_box'>left side</div>
    <div class='left r_box'>
      <div class='fixie'>I'm Fixed at some point</div>
    </div>
    <div style='clear:both;'></div>
  </div>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  
  <div class="limit">
    stop
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: That's adding/removing the class `sticky`, not `fixed`. If you correct that it should work. If not, please add a working example to the question

Comment: Maby your name of the class is incorrect. What exactly not working?

Comment: Sorry! I updated my question, example: https://codepen.io/KaioRocha/pen/QWLEWBY

Comment: Your codepen doesn't include jQuery. Add it, and it works fine.

Comment: I forgot that, sticky works, but it is not removed when it reaches the 'limit' div. That's the point

Comment: If that was the point you've not mentioned it anywhere in the question previously.

Comment: "I need that when the .fixie div arrives at another div, the sticky class is removed. This way is not working."

Comment: Brilliant question! Perfect answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `div` position of `.limit` with `window_top` and if the scroll reaches `stop` you can removed `sticky` class. i.e :

```js
function sticky_relocate_2() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('.r_box').offset().top - 100;
    
   

    if (window_top > div_top) {
            $('.fixie').addClass('sticky')


    } 
    //if window top reaches the limit removed class
    if(window_top > $('.limit').position().top){
   
        $('.fixie').removeClass('sticky');
    }
}

$(window).scroll(sticky_relocate_2);
```

```css
.wrap{ 
    height:2000px; 
    width:100%;
}
.fixed_line{ 
    border-bottom:1px solid #000; 
    height:100px; width:100%; 
    margin-bottom:100px; 
    background-color:#72cbeb; 
    position:fixed;
}
.container{ 
    padding-top:200px;
}
.left{ 
    float:left; 
}
.l_box{ 
    width:200px; 
    background-color:#CCC; 
}
.r_box, .fixie{ 
    width:100px; 
    background-color:#999; 
}

.sticky{
  position:fixed;
  top:100px;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='fixed_line'></div>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='left l_box'>left side</div>
    <div class='left r_box'>
      <div class='fixie'>I'm Fixed at some point</div>
    </div>
    <div style='clear:both;'></div>
  </div>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  pr <br>
  
  <div class="limit">
    stop
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems that div only deactivates when window_top gets div `limit`. Could we make `div_top` by touching div` limit` disable position?

Comment: You need to go to `div_top` if `window_top` reaches `limit` . am i right ? can you elaborate it more ?